# Reading and writing to boxed double values thread safe with no lock?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, volatile, boxing

From the words of MS, reads and writes (along with other operations) to doubles are not atomic and thus not thread safe. I wanted to see if I can make reads and writes to double thread safe by boxing the double values and making the reference to the boxed value volatile. Below is a class that demonstrates my use of boxed doubles across a worked and consumer thread:

```
public class Program {
    public volatile static object objCounter;
    public static AutoResetEvent Finish = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Worker thread that writes to the boxed double values
        Task.Run(() => {
            double dCounter = 0d;
            while (!Finish.WaitOne(100, false)) {
                dCounter += 1.5d;

                // Box dCounter into objCounter -
                // Copy double value to new location on the heap
                // and point the objCounter to this location on the heap
                objCounter = (object)dCounter; 
            }
        });

        // Consumer thread that reads the boxed double values
        for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Double counter value = {0}",objCounter));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Finish.Set();
    }
}
```

I believe the above code is thread safe for the following reasons:

1. When the worker thread writes the double to `objCounter`, it must create a new location on the heap, copy the double value to that new location on the heap, then atomically copy the refence to the new heap location to `objCounter`. This atomic copy of the refence(pointer) to `objCounter` is guaranteed to be atomic straight from the mouth of MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#96-atomicity-of-variable-references – (See 9.6 Atomicity of variable references) It is important to note that a new location on the heap is created for every time we box the double, if we didn’t create a new location on the heap than this would not be thread safe.
2. Since `objCounter` is volatile, there would be no memory visibility issues between the worker and consumer threads of the reference that points to the memory location on heap that contains the current double value.

**Am I correct to assume my use of boxed doubles across a worker and consumer thread as specified above is thread safe?**

Comment: @SolomonSlow I see what you saying by term "Thread safe". Yes, you are correct by thread safe I do mean I will only see integer multiples of 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is thread-safe. Since the `objCounter` is a [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) field, the two lines below:

```
objCounter = (object)dCounter;
Console.WriteLine(objCounter);
```

...are equivalent to those:

```
Volatile.Write(ref objCounter, (object)dCounter);
Console.WriteLine(Volatile.Read(ref objCounter));
```

Both `Volatile` methods create memory barriers. The [`Volatile.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.write) ensures that the processor will not move the instructions assosiated with creating the `objCounter` instance, after this call. And the [`Volatile.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read) ensures that the processor will not move the instructions assosiated with displaying the `objCounter` in the console, before this call. So the thread that displays the `objCounter` will always see a fully initialized instance.